# Could "siblings-in-law" word or "relatives up to the second degree" sentence also means my wife's grandmother?

Tags: word-meaning

Could "siblings-in-law" word or "relatives up to the second degree" sentence in the following sentence also mean my wife's grandmother?

> *Relatives up to the second degree* of consanguinity or affinity and *siblings-in-law*.

Comment: [***sibling***](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sibling) - *each of two or more children or offspring having one or both parents in common; a **brother or sister.*** So no - that *doesn't* include grandparents (yours, ***or*** your wife's).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I edited a little the question. Could you give me an answer?

Comment: You're now asking a different question! Originally you asked whether "siblings-in-law" includes grandparents, which I voted to close because any dictionary will give you a definition similar to the one I linked to above. Now you're asking whether your wife's grandmother is a "second-degree relative" - but that term is usually only meaningful in terms of ***consanguinity*** - that's *blood* relatives ***who share DNA***. Unless there's something else involved, your wife's consanguineous relatives don't share ***any*** "personal" DNA with you (they're consanguineous to ***her***, not you! ).

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for your important comments and I'm sorry I wasn't as accurate as I should from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - neither of these terms can describe the grandparent of your marriage partner.

A *sibling* is specifically a brother or a sister, not any other relative; so "*[siblings-in-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibling-in-law)*" can only refer to any brother-in-law or sister-in-law.

A "[second-degree-relative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-degree_relative)" is someone with one other family member between you and them, or who shares 25% of your genes. It includes uncles, aunts, nephews, nieces, grandparents, grandchildren, half-siblings, and double cousins. As there are *two* family members between you and your wife's grandmother (your wife, and her parent), and because you do not share *any* genetics with your wife's grandmother (at least I hope not), she cannot be your second-degree-relative. She *is*, however, your *wife's* second-degree-relative.

Comment: Thank you @Astralbee for your answer and you have right - I do not share any genetics with my wife's grandmother :)

Comment: You're right, of course. But as I understand things, [Humans share 50% DNA with bananas](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/weird-news/humans-share-50-dna-bananas-2482139) - which I'm willing to believe doesn't imply any family history of sexual deviancy (I think bananas are "asexual" anyway, so they probably wouldn't be interested in such hanky-panky! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers We're also 60% water, so does that mean we are more closely related to a swimming pool than a banana? I think you may be taking the genetics aspect too literally. We get 50% of our genetics from each parent, but our siblings don't necessarily get the same 50% from each. From a scientific perspective, we might only share 25% of the same genetics with our own full-blood siblings. But the definition above is lifted from the Wikipedia entry I cited and is more about the percentage of the shared *gene pool* than your actual measured genetics.